# python dict key iteration for loop and comprehension gives different result

Tags: python, for-loop, key, list-comprehension

iterating dict keys in a for loop gives (correctly or as desired):

```
>>> for ky in myDict.keys():
...     print(ky)
...
a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
a6
```

Whereas -- putting in a comprehension gives -- why the list of None??:

```
>>> [print(ky) for ky in myDict.keys()]
a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
a6
[None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: `print()` prints its arguments and returns `None`. What do you expect to be in the list?

Comment: try this `print([ky for ky in myDict.keys()])`

Comment: thank you -- newbie error on my part -- didn't know print had a return value

Comment: In Python every function has a return value: if a function has no return statement, it returns `None`.

Answer (score -2):

`print` is a function that has `None` as a return value.